# How do i combine asynchronous js with vuex store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

So i've been trying to make a 'log in' for my vue app. User logs in by clicking on the button and running the following method:

```
async signIn() {
      this.getfireBaseData(await this.authenticate());
    },
```

Here are both of the methods used inside the previous one:

```
    async authenticate() {
      auth
        .signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then((result) =>
          this.$store.commit("setUserData", {
            email: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.email,
            picture: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.picture,
            name: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.name,
          })
        )
        .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
      return this.$store.state.userData;
    },
    async getfireBaseData(x) {
      db.collection("rooms")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          this.firebaseData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            data: doc.data(),
          }));
          console.log(x);
          if (x) {
            this.$router.push(`/rooms/${this.firebaseData[0].id}`);
          }
        });
    },
```

And the store:

```
state: {
    userData: null,
  },
  mutations: {
    setUserData(state, payload) {
      state.userData = payload;
    },
  }
```

I'm expecting it to run getfireBaseData as soon as the authenticate() resolves its promise. For some reason - when i'm running the code for the first time - authenticate() leaves me with fullfiled promise with the value of "null" - the value in the store. It seems like authenticate() does modify the store value but does not return it as i run it instantly. Any solves to that issue?

Comment: use `await auth().....` and `await db.collection....` to wait for asyc code to finish

Comment: ok so the only thing i did was adding await before auth.signIn...... and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are returning directly your store data from authenticate(), not the promise chain.
So you are not waiting your auth.signInWithPopup but resolve directly the current value of your store.

try to returning directly auth.signInWithPopup(provider) and return your userData from the resolve callback or via an other "then" after your catch.

But it might not be a good idea to mix async/await with .then.catch.
It's error prone.